# How to set a default programming-language in Npp?

Tags: notepad++, tex

I use Npp (Notepad++) for compiling Tex-Files. But everytime I reopen any tex-file, Npp does not recognize it and uses for highlightnings another language, and I have to choose language->tex by myself. Because I use Npp ONLY for tex: How to set Npp, s.t. every file is interpreted by default as an tex-file?

Thanks.

Comment: Notepad++ chooses what language to format it in depending on the file extension of the opened file. I just tried saving a .tex file and when I opened it it automatically opened it as a tex file. I don't think there's a way to make every single file it opens open as a tex file.

Comment: frasmacon is right, N++ formats a file depending the file extension. Can you let us know the extension of your files?

Comment: As I wrote, my files have all the extension .tex, but Npp does not choose the language correctly, I have to do that by myself. I use the last version of Npp.

Comment: found the answer here: http://superuser.com/a/58682/235752

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings -> Style Configurator. From the language list on the far left, choose Tex. Below that is a field titled Default ext. It should contain, by default, the extension "tex". If for some reason it doesn't, or if you want more extensions to be treated as tex, add them to the next field titled User ext.

Answer (score 2):

Settings -> Preferences

Then under New Document, select Default language from the dropdown list:

[image: Select Default language]

Answer (score 0):

For me in Notepad++v7.2.1

1) under Preferences --> Default Directory --> Choosing the 3rd radio button and changing the directory to the location where my needes files are.
AND
2) In the style configurator I added the extra extension under user ext. (sas) in my case solved my problem.

Comment: The question was how to change the default programming language in notepad++. I could change it with those 2 steps Ive written above.

Answer (score -1):

You have to go in your Options -> Styles Menu, here you can choose the Default including the programming language

Comment: Can you give an explicit instruction please how to choose the default including there? I dont understand it.